# Red or green squiggly lines in Solution Explorer in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

What are these green squiggly lines in VS 2013 Solution Explorer underlining solution name, project name and file name and how to remove them? I just opened the solution and no files are checked out or modified.

[image]

No code is underlined and no errors or warnings are detected by Visual Studio in the file:

[image]

Comment: Green underlines are warnings. What code is underlined in `MainViewModel.cs`?

Comment: Since when is green a warning?

Comment: Has been for years, I believe.

Comment: Are you using resharper? If so, then they may be code suggestions.

Comment: Yes, but the same version of ReSharper did no such thing in VS 2010 and if there were ReSharper code suggestions in the file some code would be underlined... correct?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2013 does that.
Here's the user request page:
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2455502-show-errors-in-solution-explorer-like-eclipse-does

You can disable the feature by turning it OFF from Visual Studio Options menu > Productivity Power Tools > Solution Error Visualizer.

Comment: Still the solution for VS 2017 with Productivity Power Tools 2017.